# every real symmetric matrix has at least one real eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Why every real symmetric matrix has at least one real eigenvalue?

Comment: Every real symmetric matrix $A$ has at least one eigenvalue $\lambda$. To  prove that it is real, see here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209094/proving-the-eigenvalues-of-a-real-symmetric-matrix-are-real?lq=1

Comment: The $0\times 0$ matrix does not have any (real or other) eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3):

Since none of the linked questions really address the question of *existence* (as opposed to realness) of eigenvalues at all (the complex numbers probably being assumed as workhorse here), I'll suggest an approach that avoids depending on complexification.

Let $V=\Bbb R^n$ with $n>0$ (a necessary assumption, see my comment) equipped with its standard inner product. Then let $B(v,w)=( v\mid A(w))$ be the symmetric bilinear form on $V$ defined by$~A$, and $Q:v\mapsto B(v,v)$ its quadratic form. The latter is a differentiable real-valued function, with deriviative at $v$ in the direction $w$ given by $Q'(v)(w)=B(v,w)+B(w,v)=2B(v,w)$.

By continuity, $Q$ assumes a maximal value on the (non-empty and compact) unit sphere, say at $v_m$. Then the derivative of $Q$ at $v_m$ in any tangent direction to the unit sphere at$~v_m$ is zero. Those tangent directions are all $w\in V$ with $w\perp v_m$; that is one has
$$
  2B(v_m,w) = 0
  \qquad\text{whenever $w\perp v_m$.}
$$
Given that $B(v,w)=( v\mid A(w)) = ( A(v)\mid w)$ one concludes that $A(v_m)$ (being perpendicular to all vectors $w\perp v_m$) is a scalar multiple of$~v_m$, so $v_m$ is an eigenvector (over$~\Bbb R$) of$~A$, QED.

N.B., you can extend this to the construction of a orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for$~A$ by restricting $B$ and $Q$ to the orthogonal complement $\langle v_m\rangle^\perp$, and then applying induction on the dimension.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what you mean by "tangent direction", but I don't see why $Q$ has zero derivative in every tangent direction at $v_m$. For example if $Q(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ (so $A$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix), then $Q$ is constant along the unit circle, and it's not true that every directional derivative of $Q$ is zero along the unit circle.

Comment: @Ehsaan: I don't get what you want to say. Every directional derivative of $Q$ at a point of the unit circle _in the direction tangent to the unit circle at that point_ is zero. Simply because one can compute a directional derivative at $p$ in direction $v$ along any parametrised curve $\gamma$ with $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$; in particular one can arrange $\gamma$ to have its images contained in the unit circle, in which case $Q(\gamma(t))$ is constant and its derivative $0$.